# Create Nested Json Obj in R for httr::POST

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

I am new to R and trying hit an endpoint. I already have got the token. Now using that token i want to hit the endpoint and get the data.

The problem is in creating a nested dictionary

i am able to create:

```
 {
    "a":["A"],
    "b":["B"]
 }
```

what i want:

```
{
 "c": {
       "a":["A"],
       "b":["B"]
 }
}
```

Target/Final Code...

```
url <- "http:xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xx?"
req <- httr::POST(url, body=body, httr::add_headers(Authorization = token))
```

---

among few things that i have tried...

```
a<-c("A")
b<-c("B")
body<- jsonlite::toJSON(data.frame(a=a, b=b) ) 
body
```

**output: [{"a":"A","b":"B"}]**

```
body2<- jsonlite::toJSON(data.frame(c=body ) )
```

gives error:
cannot coerce class ""json"" to a data.frame

so probably something like this should have been done...

```
body2<- jsonlite::toJSON(data.frame(c=fromJSON(body) ) ) 
body2
```

but output is...     `[{"c.a":"A","c.b":"B"}]`

---

Then i tried...

```
json <- toJSON('{"a": ["A"],"b": ["B"]}') 
json
body<- jsonlite::toJSON(data.frame(c=fromJSON(json) ) )
body
```

**output: ["{\"a\": [\"A\"],\"b\": [\"B\"]}"]**

---

... now i am completely lost and confused.

*tried to understand:
[POST encripted request with JSON body on R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749105/post-encripted-request-with-json-body-on-r)
[Nested JSON to dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179122/nested-json-to-dataframe-in-r)
[Convert Nested JSON Object into data Frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559547/convert-nested-json-object-into-data-frame-in-r)
[Import data from file contaning nested JSON objects in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318706/import-data-from-file-contaning-nested-json-objects-in-r)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This demonstrates what you are trying to achieve. Without more code I dont know if this solves your problem.

```
body <- list()
innerBody <- list()
innerBody$a <- "A"
innerBody$b <- "B"
body$c <- innerBody
jsonlite::toJSON(body, pretty = TRUE)
```

> {   "c": {
>       "a": ["A"],
>       "b": ["B"]   }
>   }